# Finding title case within sentence using regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to use Regex to extract title cased phrases and word that occur within the sentences.

Effort so far:

```
(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+
```

This regex code when applied on the sample sentence below finds those words shown as bold. But I need to ignore words like This and Whether (sentence starters).

**Sample Sentence:**

**This** is a **Sample Sentence** to check the **Real Value** of this code. **Whether** it works or **Not** depends upon the result.

**Expectation:**

This is a **Sample Sentence** to check the **Real Value** of this code. Whether it works or **Not** depends upon the result.

Useful code:

```
import regex as re

text='This is a Sample Sentence to check the Real Value of this code. Whether it works or Not depends upon the result. A State Of The Art Technology is needed to do this work.'
rex=r'(?<!^|[.!?]\ )\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\ [A-Z][a-z]+)*\b'

matches = re.finditer(rex,text)
results = [match[0] for match in matches]
print(results)
```

Result:

```
['Sample Sentence', 'Real Value', 'Not', 'State Of The Art Technology']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your regex flavor supports Lookbehinds, I would use something like this:

```
(?<!^|\.\ )\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\ [A-Z][a-z]+)*\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqKhLz/1)**.

This will support words that are preceded by an abbreviation, punctuation, or pretty much anything other than a period (end of previous sentence).

---

**Edit:**

As per [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)'s suggestion in the comments, it's probably better to include `!` and `?` in the Lookbehind to support sentences ending with either of them, not just the period:

```
(?<!^|[.!?]\ )\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\ [A-Z][a-z]+)*\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqKhLz/2)**.

Comment: You should probably allow for sentences to end in `?` or `!` as well.

Comment: @Nick It can indeed end with anything. It just won't be included in the match (which is what I believe the OP intended). I think that the OP's pattern including the trailing whitespace was just a side-effect of them trying to include multiple consecutive words in one match.

Comment: I was referring to your negative lookbehind, it would be better with `[.!?]` than `\.`

Comment: @Programmer_nltk you might find this solution more flexible if your sentence structure can include punctuation in the middle of them.

Answer (score 2):

If your sentence is always single spaced, you can use a positive lookbehind for a letter and a space to find the start of a title-cased expression:

```
(?<=[a-z,] )(?:[A-Z][a-z]+(?![a-z]).)+
```

This regex allows for the expression to end in punctuation instead of just a space (e.g. `the Final Result.`).

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3oJ85I/2)

Comment: This will not match things like `Bb` in `AA Bb` or `Aa, Bb`. Although not included in OP's example, I think they would want to match those as well (I could be wrong thoough).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm not sure about `AA Bb` but `Aa, Bb` might well be valid. It's a good point.